# cmake use library target in added executable

Tags: c++, cmake

I have started a new c++ project which has several executables and a relatively large amount of shared code.

```
root
    CMakeLists.txt
    Common
    Application1 
    Application2
    ....
```

So the multiple applications all get compiled with their unittests without issues. But since they depend on the shared code in Common I have the recompile the shared code for each project once I update something there.

So I am wondering if it would be possible to add the library target. And build that first. And then I link my code to that library.

This seems like a relatively normal thing to do but I can't find anything about it on google.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. 
You have to add a CMakeLists file to the Common folder and in it you compile it as a library

```
# Add required source files.
add_library(Common ...)

# Include required header files. They must be public to be recognized where they are needed.
target_include_directories(Common PUBLIC ...)
```

Then in the project's CMakeLists you use:

```
add_subdirectory(Common) // Will call the other CMakelists
...
# Link to the required libraries.
target_link_libraries(Application Common)
```